# Remove Custom UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

I've customized my UINavigationBar with an image like that :

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"NavigationBar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

When I launch a video my custom NavigationBar (with the picture) is on the top or **I would like to have the default navigationBar style when I'm playing a video**.

I tried to hide the navigationBar with

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:animated];
```

but it just remove the navigationBar in my controller but I still have the NavigationBar.png when I'm playing a video. I tried to set the barstyle but it doesn't work either ...

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
```

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using an **extern boolean** variable say: `isVideo`;

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if(!isVideo){
       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"NavigationBar.png"];
       [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    }
    else{
       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"SimpleNavigationBarImage.png"];
       [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
    }
}
@end
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks,

Madhup

Comment: Hi Madhup and thank's for your answer. 

That could work but it will change the image of my NavigationBar instead of using the default one.